# C++ equivalent of this Python code for dictionaries/lists?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, python-3.2

In my Python code I have an issue that I need clarified before I start translating to c++: how to make proper dictionaries/lists that I can use the equivalent of "if var in *_*" in.

arbitrary example that needs translation:

```
CONFIRMATION = ('yes', 'yeah', 'yep', 'yesh', 'sure', 'yeppers', 'yup')
DECLINATION = ('no', 'nope', 'too bad', 'nothing')

varResponse = str(input('yes or no question'))
if varResponse in CONFIRMATION: 
    doSomething()
elif varResponse in DECLINATION: 
    doSomethingElse()
else:
    doAnotherThing()
```

It's fairly easy to do similar tasks using arrays, like:

```
if (userDogName == name[0])
    execute something;
```

but what I need is something like:

```
if (userDogName is one of a population of dog names in a dictionary)
    execute something;
```

Comment: If the list isn't too large, you can just do a linear search on an array.

Comment: I have some rather large lists, but I'll consider that for the small ones. What should I do for the large ones?

Comment: Does the ordering of the elements matter, and can you have duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the STL container class `set`. It uses balanced binary trees:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::set<std::string> set;
  std::set<std::string>::const_iterator iter;

  set.insert("yes");
  set.insert("yeah");

  iter = set.find("yess");

  if (iter != set.end( ))
  {
    std::cout << "Found:" << *iter;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Not found!";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this method, but have an issue; what would I do if I had say 25 terms? Surely I wouldn't do set.insert("term") 25 times?

Comment: In C++11 you can use initializer lists. Just search for `std::initializer_list` to understand the concept. In your program you would simply write: `set<string> as = {"a", "A" ...`.

Comment: In older versions you would use a constructor of `set` that gets two pointers and assumes that these point to the beginning and end of an array, which is then used to initialize your set.

Comment: But in a real world application you would probably not hard code the lists, but read them from some kind of configuration file? That was my thought behind using the `insert`.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 permits a solutions that's very similar to the Python code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

set<string> CONFIRMATION = {"yes", "yeah", "yep", "yesh", "sure", "yeppers", "yup"};
set<string> DECLINATION = {"no", "nope", "too bad", "nothing"};

int main() {
  cout << "yes or no question";
  string varResponse;
  getline(cin, varResponse);
  if (CONFIRMATION.find(varResponse) != CONFIRMATION.end()) {
    doSomething();
  } else if (DECLINATION.find(varResponse) != DECLINATION.end()) {
    doSomethingElse();
  } else {
    doAnotherThing();
  }
}
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: No. I only have access to Clang.

Answer (score 1):

Well, C++ isn't well suited for small throw-off programs, because it doesn't provide much infra-structure. You're meant to create your own infra-structure (such as, well, even just plain sets!) on top of the standard library. Or use some 3<sup>rd</sup>-party libraries, i.e. *your choice*.

So while Python comes with batteries included, with C++ there is no strong pressure to accept the particular provided batteries (because there are none), but you have to at least choose batteries.

For just the basic code, the Python snippet

```
CONFIRMATIONS = ("yes", "yeah", "yep", "yesh", "sure", "yeppers", "yup")
DECLINATIONS = ("no", "nope", "too bad", "nothing")

response = raw_input( "yes or no? " )
if response in CONFIRMATIONS:
    pass # doSomething()
elif response in DECLINATIONS:
    pass # doSomethingElse()
else:
    pass #doAnotherThing()
```

can look like this in C++:

```
typedef Set< wstring > Strings;

Strings const   confirmations   = temp( Strings() )
    << L"yes" << L"yeah" << L"yep" << L"yesh" << L"sure" << L"yeppers" << L"yup";
Strings const   declinations    = temp( Strings() )
    << L"no" << L"nope" << L"too bad" << L"nothing";

wstring const response = lineFromUser( L"yes or no? " );
if( isIn( confirmations, response ) )
{
    // doSomething()
}
else if( isIn( declinations, response ) )
{
    // doSomethingElse()
}
else
{
    // doAnotherThing()
}
```

But then, it relies on some infra-structure having been defined, like the `Set` class:

```
template< class TpElem >
class Set
{
public:
    typedef TpElem      Elem;

private:
    set<Elem>   elems_;

public:
    Set& add( Elem const& e )
    {
        elems_.insert( e );
        return *this;
    }

    friend Set& operator<<( Set& s, Elem const& e )
    {
        return s.add( e );
    }

    bool contains( Elem const& e ) const
    {
        return (elems_.find( e ) != elems_.end());
    }
};

template< class Elem >
bool isIn( Set< Elem > const& s, Elem const& e )
{
    return s.contains( e );
}
```

I used an `operator<<` because still as of 2012 Visual C++ does not support C++11 curly braces list initialization.

Here `set`  is `std::set` from the standard library.

And, hm, the `temp` thingy:

```
template< class T >
T& temp( T&& o ) { return o; }
```

And, more infra-structure, the `lineFromUser` function:

```
wstring lineFromUser( wstring const& prompt )
{
    wcout << prompt;

    wstring result;
    getline( wcin, result )
        || throwX( "lineFromUser: std::getline failed" );
    return result;
}
```

Which, relies on a `throwX` function:

```
bool throwX( string const& s ) { throw runtime_error( s ); }
```

But that's about all, except that you have to put the C++ code I showed first, into some function, say, call that `cppMain`, and invoke that from your `main` function (even more infra-structure to define!):

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        cppMain();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        wcerr << "!" << x.what() << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

So, to do things even half-way properly in C++, there is some steep overhead.

C++ is mainly for larger programs, and Python (which I often use) for smallish programs.

And yes, I know that some students may or will react to that statement, either they feel that it's a slur on C++ to say that it's no good for small programs (hey, I make those all the time!) and/or it's a slur on Python to say that it's no good for large systems (hey, haven't you heard of YouTube, you dumb incompetent person?), but, that's the way that it is. Sometimes it can be more convenient to use the hammer one has to fasten a screw, so sometimes I, for example, use C++ to do some small task. But generally that's because it would be too much hassle to install Python on the machine at hand, and in general, to do a task X, it's best to use tools that have been designed for X-like work.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using `std::find` on any Standard Template Library container.

```
std::vector<std::string> answers;
std::string input;
...
if(std::find(answers.begin(), answers.end(), input) != answers.end()) {
    /* input was found in answers */
} else {
    /* input was not found in answers */
}
```

For larger lists, it may be better to store your lists in a `std::set` object instead, as Tilo suggested. `std::find` will work the same.